# Fetch method is not working in Node but in web-browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fetch

I've tried using unirest package with code that I copied from Postman and It works, but when I try to do the same with node-fetch, It fails. If I copy this code to Chrome or Mozilla It works fine somehow. What am I missing here?

```
  const test = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://vhost3.lnu.se:20080/dinner/login', {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: 'username=zeke&password=coys&submit=login',
    method: 'POST'
  })
  const data = await res
  return data
}
```

This is the response in node terminal:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],  
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _transformState: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'http://vhost3.lnu.se:20080/dinner/login/booking',
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 1
 }
}
```

Comment: `fetch` is only available in the browser, you mentioned `node-fetch`, is that what you're importing and using here or...

Comment: Yes, in node i import node-fetch. This function is basically copied from browser with copy as fetch feature.

Comment: What is the point of `async/await` if you still resolve the promise in the callback? Also test() returns a promise

Comment: Refactored it a bit, not working anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is using you browser cookies. When u login to that server. It save some cookies(token). SO that u don't have to sign in again. Postman uses chrome cookies. That is why working. Try on incognito mode.
2. Other reason, there may be proxy enable for your browser. than u have to pass proxy detail in node app too.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. So i need to get the cookies first and then use them in options?

Comment: better login first, using node. Look for auth API. Login and get token. than use token for subsequent calls. you cant get cookies if secure.

Comment: Well i am trying to login. That's what this function is all about. I know username and password and trying to login to the site with fetch.